# getting unexpected output when shifting elements of an array

Tags: arrays, c

i have an array arr[]
then i take input
then if the digits are 9999 then i make them zero and shift them 1 index to right and declare index 0 as '1'

```
if(carry == 1){
            arr[len]='0';
            for(i=len;i>0;i--){
                arr[i] = arr[i-1]; //arr[i+1] = arr[i] works fine
            }
            arr[0]='1';
        }
```

but the problem is if i give index 9999 the out put is 10000m or 10000k or 10000o

i tried changing arr[i] = arr[i-1]; to arr[i+1] = arr[i] and it works fine but as the length is at index one more then the last char of array why do i have to use i+1 instead of 1?

Comment: `arr` is a `char[]` and supposed to contain a string?! Then you are missing the `NULL`-delimiter at `arr[len+1]`. Take care not to go out of bounds.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strings in c (aka char*) are meant to end with '\0' (which is ascii 0). When outputting an array, the loop stops when it finds a 0 value. As `arr[len]` isn't 0 ('\0' as a char) but '0' (which is ascii 48), the loop doesn't stop at `arr[len]`. Many values in memory are 0 but generally values in memory, you did not set are random. Chances are the next value after arr[len] is not 0, but eventually there will be a 0 and the iteration will stop or you encounter memory you do not own (which results in a SEGFAULT). So to have predictable results, you should reserve one char more for your array than the displayable string and set the last one to 0.
Also. You should start at len-1 and set `arr[i] = arr[i+1]`, because now, you are overriding the assignment you did just before the loop. Pay attention, that your array should have length len+2 as at index len there is '0' and at index len+1 there should be '\0'.
Hope I helped :)